# Suppose $\dim V=n$, $\dim W =m$, and $T\in L(V,W$)...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T\in L(V, W)$, and set $n = \dim V$ and $m= \dim W$.

(a.) Suppose $n < m$. Show that there exists a basis $w_1, \dots, w_m$ of $W$ such that the last $m-n$ rows of $M(T)$ consist only of $0$s for every choice of basis of $V$.

(b.) Suppose $n > m$. Show that there exists a basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $V$ such that the last $n-m$ columns of $M(T)$ consist only of $0$s for every choice of basis of $W$.

Please help!

Comment: (a.) makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hope this makes more sense now!

Comment: @anomaly You can actually just use $\dim$, instead of putting it into text mode.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Thanks, that's much easier. (I have a long file of DeclareMathOperator settings for my own tex documents, and I forget which are in the default.)

Answer (score 0):

For (a), choose a basis corresponding the decomposition $W = (\text{im } T) \oplus (\text{im  }T)^\perp$, noting that $\dim (\text{im }T)^\perp = m - \dim (\text{im }T) \geq m - n$. For (b), choose a basis corresponding to the decomposition $V = (\ker T)^\perp \oplus (\ker T)$, noting that $\dim (\ker T) \geq n - m$.

Comment: Is there another way to solve this problem? I am not familiar with decomposition and just this general method of this solution. Thanks!

Comment: What are you familiar with, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hints: (a) Any $T(v)$ can be represented by a linear combination of a basis of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

(b) Each vector in $\operatorname{ker}(T)$ will be mapped to zero. What do the columns of $M(T)$ stand for?